# Need help Asymptotic Analysis

Tags: algorithm, asymptotic-complexity

In the Asymptotic analysis, we always talk about input sizes larger than a constant value. It might be possible that those large inputs are never given to your software and an algorithm which is asymptotically slower, always performs better for your particular situation. So, you may end up choosing an algorithm that is Asymptotically slower but faster for your software. What does it mean?

Comment: It means you should test and see what works best for your particular situation.

Comment: what is that Constant value is referred to here?

Comment: @sauravism it means asymptotic analysis results will not be accurate if input is small. **Being small** normally depends on your problem.

Answer (score 1):

For what **constant value** means in your context, compare these 2 algorithms' asymptotic analysis results:

```
Algorithm A -> O(5*n^2)
Algorithm B -> O(2^n)
```

Now for understanding better, check how they increase:

```
n | Algorithm A | Algorithm B
1 | 5           | 2
2 | 20          | 4
3 | 40          | 9
4 | 90          | 16
5 | 125         | 32
6 | 180         | 64
7 | 245         | 128
8 | 320         | 256
9 | 405         | 512 <-- Threshold
10| 500         | 1024
```

You can think of these numbers as time spent for running algorithm and lower numbers means quicker algorithm. As you see, when `n<=8` numbers for `Algorithm A` is bigger than `Algorithm B`. So if your input set is too small, then you can use `Algorithm B` and get better results. But if your input gets bigger, in this case `n>=9`, results of `Algorithm B` will become worse than `Algorithm A`. So for bigger inputs, `Algorithm A` works better. In your question context, **Constant value** means a number like `9` which create this threshold for comparing algorithms.

As a side note, When you Asymptotically analyze an algorithm, there is **always** a constant value such as `C` multiplied in your analysis result, e.g. `O(C*n^2)`. This constant value normally have a significant effect on selecting what algorithm is more suitable if your input data is small. Just don't mistake this constant value with the one in your question context.